# Conditional probability question on defective item problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to understand the following problem and solution from [this page Example 1.19](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_0_conditional_probability.php).  What does the sample space and $A_1 $event look like?  Also, how is $P(A_2|A_1)$ (conditional probability) established?  It's my understanding conditional probability uses the form $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$.   I don't see that occurring here.  Thanks!

In a factory there are 100 units of a certain product, 5 of which are defective. We pick three units from the 100 units at random. What is the probability that none of them are defective?

Let us define $A_i$ as the event that the $i$th chosen unit is not defective, for $i = 1, 2, 3$.  We are interested in $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$.

$P(A_1) = 95/100$

Given that the first chosen item was good, the second item will be chosen from 94 good units and 5 defective units, thus:

$P(A_2|A_1) = 94/99$

Given that the first and second chosen items were okay, the third item will be chosen from 93 good units and 5 defective units, tus:

$P(A_3|A_2, A_1) = 93/98$

Thus:

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_2, A_1)$

$ = 95/100 * 94/99 * 93/98 = 0.8560$

Comment: Each event of choosing a unit is independent from the previous events, so there is no conditional probability in play here.

Comment: Does that mean the sample space changes with each event?  Also, is the solution wrong?  I'm reading this on https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_0_conditional_probability.php

Comment: the solution looks good.

Comment: @PeteBabe but the solution uses conditional probability which you said is not occurring

Comment: for independent events, $P(A|B) = P(A)$, or equivalently, $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution agrees with the text.  I believe these are dependent events.
The sample space or elementary events of the units chosen is:

$E = \{U_1,U_2 ... U_{100}\} x \{U_1,U_2 ... U_{99}\} x \{U_1,U_2 ... U_{98}\}$

The first event and subsequent events are calculated:

$A_1 = E \cap \{U_1,U_2..U_{95}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{99}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{98}\}$

The first result:

$P(A_1) = |A_1|/|E| = (95*99*98) / (100*99*98) = 95/100$

$A_2 = E \cap \{U_1,U_2..U_{100}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{94}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{98}\}$

$P(A_2 \cap A_1) = |A_2 \cap A_1|/|E| = (95*94*98) / (100*99*98) = (95*94)/(100*99)$
we also note $A_2$ and $A_1$ are independent because:
$P(A_2 \cap A_1) = P(A_1)P(A_2) = (95*94)/(100*99) = 95/100 * 94/99$

The second result:
$P(A_2|A_1) = P(A_2 \cap A_1)/P(A_1) = (95*94)/(100*99) * 100/95 = 94/99$

because $A_2$ and $A_1$ are independent, $P(A_2|A_1) = P(A_1)P(A_2)/P(A_1) = P(A_2) = 94/99$.

$A_3 = E \cap \{U_1,U_2..U_{100}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{99}\} x \{U_1,U_2..U_{93}\}$

$P(A_3 \cap A_2 \cap A_1) = |A_3 \cap A_2 \cap A_1|/|E| = (95*94*93) / (100*99*98)$

$P(A_2 \cap A_1) = |A_2 \cap A_1|/|E| = (95*94*98)/(100*99*98) = (95*94)/(100*99)$

we note $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = (95*94*93)/(100*99*98) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A1,A2) = P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3) = 95/100 * 94/99 * 93/98$, so $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are also independent.

The third result:
$P(A_3|A_2 \cap A_1) = P(A_3 \cap A_2 \cap A_1)/P(A_2 \cap A_1) = (95*94*93)/(100*99*98) * (100*99)/(95*94)= 93/98$

alternative as $A_3, A_2, A_1$ are independent, $P(A_3|A_2 \cap A_1) = P(A_3) = 93/98$.

Answer (score 0):

The sample space is all possible ways to pick an item from the 100.

The comma "," in $P(A_3|A_2, A_1)$ can be understood as "and", which is the same as $\cap$ in this context.

Using $P(B)P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)$, we have:

$$P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3) = P(A_1 \cap A_2)P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1 \cap A_2)$$

Comment: Can you describe what the sample space would look like as a set?  Also, the event $A_i$?  I understand the conditional probability part and the later you describe, I'm confused for instance how $P(A_2|A_1) = 94/99$, specifically when substituting into $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$

Comment: The sample space would be:
$$\{\text{Normal #1 picked},\text{Normal #2 picked}, \dots, \text{Normal #95 picked}, \text{Defect #1 picked}, \dots, \text{Defect #5 picked}\}$$

The event $A_i$ is "the i-th picked item is not defective".

The sample space has never changed but it may seem that way (as evidenced by the change in denominator) but that is due to our condition $A_1$, that is, that "the first item we picked was not defective". In this condition, there are only $99$ items left to be picked, $94$ of those are nondefective.